# total number of document in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have a document table here is my query how can I sum the documents that I now have in sql and display in viewmodel by linq in asp.net core 3.1

```
public async Task<PagedResult<DocumentsVm>> GetTotal(GetDocumentsPagingRequest request)
    {
        var query = from d in _context.Documents //This is my query
                    join u in _context.Users on d.UserID equals u.Id
                    select new { d, u };
        int TotalRow = await query.CountAsync();
        var data = await query.Skip((request.PageIndex - 1) * request.PageSize)
            .Take(request.PageSize)
            .Select(x => new DocumentsVm()
            {
                ID = x.d.ID,
                Caption = x.d.Caption,
                FacultyID = x.d.FacultyOfDocumentID,
                Status = x.d.Status,
                CreateOn = x.d.CreateOn.Date,
                ViewCount = ??? //I want to display total document here
            }).ToListAsync();
        var pagedResult = new PagedResult<DocumentsVm>()
        {
            TotalRecord = TotalRow,
            Items = data
        };
        return pagedResult;
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to get the number of elements in `data`? `data.Count`?

Comment: Put `TotalRow` where your question marks are? Not really sure what you're after.

Comment: Yes , i'm trying

Comment: I am trying to get the total document for example in sql I have 3 documents then I want to get the sum equal to 3, and I want to do this when using linq in the query

Comment: `data.Count` should be the number of items in your current page, and `TotalRow` should be the total number of items in all pages.

Comment: Yes, that right